# UITextView becomes FirstResponder twice, then not thereafter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I use this code snippet to resign first responder

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I have the textView in a tableView cell. The problem I'm having is I can tap the textview and edit the field only twice, after that the textview doesn't respond to a touch anymore.

Comment: this code is okay. Problem somewhere else.
please, add more detail of your textFiled's code.

Comment: You just want the keyboard to dismiss when the user hits "Return" key?

Comment: Your code above worked just fine for me. Is only the textview becoming unresponsive or the entire app?  Do you control focus (becomeFirstResponder) somewhere else in your app?